# google adwords python api - how to get ad group bid

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I am using the adwords python api.  I need to get the bid amount and type. E.g. bid=4 ad type = cpc.

I am given the adgroup id.

Below is an example on to create and ad group.  Once created...how do I retrieve the settings?  How do I get e.g. the bid I set?

```
ad_group_service = client.GetService('AdGroupService', version='v201402')

operations = [{
      'operator': 'ADD',
      'operand': {
          'campaignId': campaign_id,
          'name': 'Earth to Mars Cruises #%s' % uuid.uuid4(),
          'status': 'ENABLED',
          'biddingStrategyConfiguration': {
              'bids': [
                  {
                      'xsi_type': 'CpcBid',
                      'bid': {
                          'microAmount': '1000000'
                      },
                  }
              ]
          }
      }
  }]
  ad_groups = ad_group_service.mutate(operations)
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the corresponding [example](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords/v201402/basic_operations/get_ad_groups.py) on `googlads`'s github page.

Basically you'll user the `AdGroupService`'s `get` method with a selector containing the right fields and predicates to retrieve an `AdGroupPage` containing the `AdGroup` objects you're interested in:

```
selector = {
      'fields': ['Id', 'Name', 'CpcBid'],
      'predicates': [
          {
              'field': 'Id',
              'operator': 'EQUALS',
              'values': [given_adgroup_id]
          }
      ]
}

page = adgroup_service.get(selector)

adgroup = page.entries[0]

print('Adgroup "%s" (%s) has CPC %s' % (adgroup.name, adgroup.id,
       adgroup.biddingStrategyConfiguration.bids.bid))
```

The available fields' names and the attributes they populate in the returned objects can be found at the [selector reference page](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/selectorfields#v201402-AdGroupService).
The `AdGroupService`'s [reference page](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201402/AdGroupService) might also be of interest.